# After installing RDS on WinServer 2016 I still can only connect with two users?

Tags: azure, active-directory, remote-desktop, rds, windows-server-2016

**What I'm trying to do:** I have a software that multiple users are supposed to use on one system. Because a standard installation of WinServer2016 can only hold a maximum of two users at once I googled and was told that a Terminal Server / RDS Server would remove this limitation so I tried that with the help of some tutorials.

All of this is happening in Azure.

**The problem:** I thought I had everything set up correctly but when I try to RDP into the machine with the third user it tells me that there's too many users and that I need to disconnect one of them to continue (as it would be if I had done nothing at all).

**What I did so far :**

- Installed a DC for my Terminal Server and let the Terminal Server join the Domain (set up the DC as DNS Server in the VNET, not in the TCP/IP Adapter settings)
- In Server Manager I started the Role and Features Menu, and chose install RDS, Quickstart, Session-Based, selected the Terminal Server
- Watched as it was installing, then had a disconnect, couldn't reconnect for a while, had to reset the connection configuration in azure and was able to reconnect.
- Upon login the installation window opened again and told me it was still doing something. After a few moments it completed with the statuss message "Successful".
- Installed the Licensing Server Role through the server manager, added my license through the server manager.
- opened gpedit.msc and made the following changes to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Session Host > Licensing :
  "Use the specified Remote Desktop license servers" > Enabled
  "Set the Remote Desktop licensing mode" > Enabled (per Device)
- Also in gpedit.msc, only in the directory Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections :
  Allow users to connect remotely by using RDS: Enabled
  Limit Number of connections: Enabled, Max Connections = 999999
  Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single RDS session = Disabled
  Allowed remote start of unlisted programs: Enabled

Still, not working. Maybe the settings reset has something to do with it? Or maybe I'm missing something obvious? Never used or set-up RDS before, except to RDP into my VMs on Azure...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right RDS server remove the limitation of connections but it is not only related with server role. You need to check to licensing method to use Terminal Server feature. you need to install Remote Desktop Services Client Access Licenses.

here is the related link from microsoft about the RDS CALs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-activate-license-server

Regards